# Having same page with different meta tags without affecting SEO

Tags: seo, meta-tags, title, meta-description, meta-keywords

I am a .NET developer, I don't know much about SEO.

How can I have single page for multiple meta descriptions and titles without downgrading my search engine oerspectives?

For example, say I have 3 questions

1. What is OOPS?
2. Explain OOPS with real life examples.
3. What are the main keypillers of OOPS?

Here the answers of these 3 questions is same so the detail page will be same but title and meta keywords and meta description of this page will be changed dynamically on the basis of question.

So basically I have 3 different URLs with same content

```
www.example.com/what-is-oops

www.example.com/explain-oops

www.example.com/key-pillers-of-oops
```

The content of these 3 pages will be same, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: You would be best making one page for your one piece of content. Trying to make 3 pages which will duplicate the one piece of content is spam.

Comment: Really, only one will rank because of duplicate content. At that point, the title, description and any other meta tag will not matter. You would have to use a canonical tag. Even then, you will not get what you want. More pages with minor changes does not mean more search traffic.

Answer (score 3):

It's not going to well in search result.

**Displaying the same content on different URL's is considered to be 'duplicate content' (Google mostly focuses on body content), no matter if your title, meta description and meta keywords ([Not supported by Google](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)) are different.**

You have three choices:

1. Provide different content for each question.
2. In same page use heading (like h2) to cover all of answer. You can even use [Jump links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash) with heading/ID.
3. If you want to display the same content as you described in the question you need to use a [canonical link tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash) Your duplicate version(s) will not appear in search results, only the canonical version.